# Why does firewall-cmd throws error "ALREADY_ENABLED" but is the port not listed when calling firewall-cmd --list-ports?

Tags: ssl, iptables, https, port, firewall-cmd

Using CentOS 7, I am trying to use `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=443/tcp --permanent` to add 443 to my allowed ports. Unfortunately this throws error `ALREADY_ENABLED: 443:tcp`. But when I use `firewall-cmd --list-ports` it does not show in the list ("80/tcp 3000/tcp 26900/tcp 26900/udp").

I suppose the issue is caused with a conflict between firewall-cmd and iptables. But I have no idea how to debug this and if this might even be possible.

Calling `firewall-cmd --list-all` results in the following list:

```
public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client
  ports: 80/tcp 3000/tcp 26900/tcp 26900/udp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command you say you ran affects the permanent configuration, not the running configuration. But you are listing the running configuration. That is why you don't see them.

You may list the permanent configuration to confirm that the rule has been added successfully.

```
firewall-cmd --list-all --permanent
```

You may add the rule to the running configuration instead:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=443/tcp
```

Or you may reload the running configuration from the permanent configuration:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

---

Also remember that firewalld has defined services for common ports, so it's not usually necessary to open them by number. For example, instead of opening ports 80/tcp and 443/tcp you could instead say:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=https
```

---

Finally, when possible, it's better to change rules in the running configuration, verify that they are working, and then save the configuration, rather than the reverse. This allows you a way to revert if something goes wrong and you accidentally lock yourself out of the system.

You can save the running configuration to the permanent configuration by running:

```
firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent
```

(But some operations only work on the permanent configuration, such as creating new zones. For these you must use `--permanent` and then immediately `--reload` the firewall.)

Comment: `firewall-cmd --reload` or `firewall-cmd --complete-reload` resolved my similar issue. Also, without specifying a zone, `firewall-cmd` shows the status on `trust` zone by default. If you poke a hole in public zone, you would need to explicitly specify the zone, e.g. `firewall-cmd --list-all --permanent --zone=public`